# Sampling vs timing profilers: Massive difference in code that uses external APIs

Tags: c++, profiling

I have a program that contains a function `fast_write()` that is entirely a wrapper around `WriteConsole()` (windows console output). The program generates a lot of console output and writes it. When profiling with the Visual Studio profiler (a sampling profiler) and Tracy (a timing profiler), the results are massively different.

Tracy shows that function taking the majority of time (~82%) while VS clocks it at 6% or so.

[image: tracy vs VS]

How can that be? I am aware that (if tracy is right) most samples won't hit "my code". And that made me realize I don't really understand how sampling profilers map such samples to code. But I would have assumed that if VS shows a percentage - that that is right.

When digging deeper with tracy, I can see that during `fast_print()`, conhost.exe takes takes up most of the time. That further confirms the theory that tracy is right.

[image]

If that is correct - does that mean that sampling profilers just try to guess which code a sample relates to? That would mean they are massively inaccurate for code that calls external code. I can hardly believe that.

Note that I also tried loading symbols from the symbol server, but it didn't change sampling counts in VS.

edit: I have manually confirmed that `fast_print()` actually takes 80% percent by just calling it twice and doing some math. That still leaves me with a massive: They can't do that, right? They can't just mis-attribute those samples without any indication?!

edit: VTune also reports same results as Tracy. So it's only VS messing up.

Comment: Sampling profiler accuracy is directly tied to runtime. You absolutely need to be running the profiled code in a loop for a long time to get any reliable results.

Comment: Obviously, sure. The code in question did not suffer from statistical problems. Ignore the low sample count in the one screenshot - this is a very reliable problem.

Comment: Another concern that comes to mind is that sample profiling statically linked small functions is really tricky. They tend to get inlined and have their content reordered within calling code. There's often no clear-cut stack frame to look at.

Comment: What do you expect? You write a program that does nothing but print to the screen, and then you're surprised that that's all it's doing?